# Count all items in a "trash bin" with a mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, count, sum

**Information:**

I have a gallery with any number of albums, in every album there can be any numbers of images.

I therefore have a table called "gallery_album" with all the albums in. I also have a table called "gallery_item" which contains all the items for every album.

**What I want to do:**

I want to be able to determine how many items is in the trash bin (albums and items) as one value.

If an album is in the trash, all the items should be in the trash as well.

Ive made the following statement, but I still need to get at SUM of the count in some kind of way so it is presented in one value, instead of one row per album. (I don't know if this is this is the best approach, so please correct me!)

(When status is -2 it is registered as being in the trash bin. I don't want to mark all items with -2 when marking an album with -2)

```
SELECT a.id, 
CASE a.status
  WHEN -2
  THEN (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM gallery_item i
    WHERE i.fk_album = a.id
  ) + 1
  ELSE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM gallery_item i
    WHERE (i.fk_album = a.id) && (i.status = -2)
  )
END as cnt, a.status
FROM gallery_album a
GROUP BY a.id
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just wrap the entire case statement with a SUM()?

Comment: Hey. Well I actually just solved it with that before, and tried to put in an answer. Will edit my post instead...

Comment: Put it as an answer and accept it so others that land on this page know what the solution was. Glad you fixed it :)

Comment: Hi Derek, I could not do that. Something about reputation I think. I have updated my post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after playing a bit around, I got it solved... But I'd still want to know if there is an even smarter way?

This is my solution:

```
SELECT SUM(albums_and_items.cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT
  CASE a.status
    WHEN -2
    THEN (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM gallery_item AS i
      WHERE i.fk_album = a.id
    ) + 1
    ELSE (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM gallery_item AS i
      WHERE (i.fk_album = a.id) && (i.status = -2)
    )
  END as cnt
  FROM gallery_album AS a
  GROUP BY a.id
) AS albums_and_items
```